# paypal how to get transaction id using checkout.js

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

How I can get the transaction id using checkout.js paypal express checkout.

I have implemented the new paypal express checkout method. I have implemented the below code for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
        var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://192.168.4.198:8083/paypalexpress/success_ipn.php';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

            client: {
                sandbox:    'AYbCnvobq09Ptmsd1TRp3019CMrSTyaAmrHNv6ox0jl86H9OZFmGCPqHqqfPtqpTYTiIuy_e5UGnclMw',
                //production: '<insert production client id>'
            },

            commit: true,

            payment: function(data, actions) {

                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '10', currency: 'USD' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },


            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                    paymentID: data.paymentID,
                    payerID:   data.payerID
                }).then(function() {
                    return actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {
                       console.log(data);
                    });
                        window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });

            }

        }, '#paypal-button-container');

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's working fine for success payment, but I am having an issue to get Payer information and txt_id after success full payment in my PHP file for update the record in the database.

How I can go with the REST API?

Please assist me if anyone have done this REST API method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not get transaction ID using checkout.js. The only way to get transaction ID is by using IPN.

Comment: Yes, I have get transaction ID using checkout.js and I have solved this already. BTW thanks for your answer.

Comment: Would you mind to answer your question and explain what you did to get the Transaction ID using checkout.js?